# Need help in calling storyboards randomly in c# via a Timer

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, timer, storyboard

Okay so I have 4 storyboards with some animation. I want to call them randomly but with an interval of 2 seconds. I tried the following, it worked partially.

TargetAnimate and target4animation were called together twice. 
target2animation and target4animation were called together twice.
target3animation was called alone thrice.

```
     namespace FF2D
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Level1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Level1 : UserControl
    {
        public Level1()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();                      
        }

        private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void UserControl_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            DispatcherTimer tgtTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
            tgtTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(tgtTimer_tick);
            tgtTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
            tgtTimer.Start();

        }

            private void tgtTimer_tick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Random _t = new Random();
                int n = _t.Next(1, 4);
                if(n == 1)
                {
                    Storyboard sb1 = this.FindResource("TargetAnimate") as Storyboard;
                    sb1.Begin();
                }

                if(n == 2)
                {
                    Storyboard sb2 = this.FindResource("target2animation") as Storyboard;
                    sb2.Begin();
                }

                if(n == 3)
                {
                    Storyboard sb3 = this.FindResource("target3animation") as Storyboard;
                    sb3.Begin();
                }

                else
                {
                    Storyboard sb4 = this.FindResource("target4animation") as Storyboard;
                    sb4.Begin();
                }
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: Store them in an array and randomize the array to get one of each in a random order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`target4animation` will be started if n = 1, 2 or 4.

Either change the `else` for `if(n == 4)` or add elses:

```
if(n == 1)
                {
                    Storyboard sb1 = this.FindResource("TargetAnimate") as Storyboard;
                    sb1.Begin();
                }

                else if(n == 2)
                {
                    Storyboard sb2 = this.FindResource("target2animation") as Storyboard;
                    sb2.Begin();
                }

                else if(n == 3)
                {
                    Storyboard sb3 = this.FindResource("target3animation") as Storyboard;
                    sb3.Begin();
                }

                else
                {
                    Storyboard sb4 = this.FindResource("target4animation") as Storyboard;
                    sb4.Begin();
                }
```